# Explicitly starting WCF service in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

I've got a WCF service with quite a long start up time (lots of data is being fetched from Oracle into RAM). It's recycled everyday at 4am which is fine, but I would like to explicitly start it at 4:30am so the first user (using Silverlight client) will not have to wait for the service to start next morning.

What would be the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

How about have your own pump priming client app start right after it's recycled?

Comment: That's a good idea. But is there a way of writing/getting more general tool which will just to force WCF service to be created? I mean, if I have 4 services, I would like to use one tool just to start them (without building a separate client for all 4 of them).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx). One of the features it provides out of the box is [automatic service activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677261.aspx) for you.